# Error while opening report folder from system administrator's account

Tags: reporting

> "You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the
>   operation you requested and your administrator has not configured a
>   way for you to verify your identity. Contact your administrator if
>   access is necessary."

Salesforce is displaying above error when I am trying to open my app's report's folder from my system administrator's account. I have checked all the security settings they are enabled for system administrator then why it is showing this?

Comment: There is a very similar question asked around the same time period - [Reports folder is not accessible to System Administrator](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/105889/102)