# Reports folder is not accessible to System Administrator

Tags: reporting, managed-package, profile, appexchange

When I try to access the reports to create a report in a Developer org, I get the following message. I don't know what the problem is.

Please help. The error is:

> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation
>   you requested and your administrator has not configured a way for you
>   to verify your identity. Contact your administrator if access is
>   necessary.

Answer (score 1):

check the profile you have assigned has create/customize report option enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the user's profile has the following permission.

1. User's "Profile" has the "Run reports" option checked in the general permissions.
2. Enable the permission "View setup & Config" on the user's profile.

Hope this helps. Thanks